# Reading a pkcs12 certificate from linux cert store and passing it to a HTTPS-Request

Tags: python, linux, client-certificates

I am trying to read a .p12 container from my linux cert store (path "/var/ssl/private/") in order to then use it as a client certificate in a https-request to an api.

```
from requests import Session
from requests_pkcs12 import Pkcs12Adapter

certPath = "/var/ssl/private/{thumbprint}.p12"
certPass = "password".encode('utf8')
caCertPath = "/var/ssl/certs/"
url = "https://example.com/api/profile"

with open(certPath, 'rb') as pkcs12_file:
    pkcs12_data = pkcs12_file.read()

with Session() as s:
    s.mount(url, Pkcs12Adapter(pkcs12_data=pkcs12_data, pkcs12_password=certPass))
    r = s.get(url, verify=caCertPath)
```

This works perfectly fine when I read the cert by its equivalent path on my windows machine.

However on a linux machine, I always get

`"Failure Exception: ValueError: Invalid password or PKCS12 data Stack"`

I made sure that the cert file was in said directory by using

```
cd /var/ssl/private/ 
ls
```

and I found the file named {thumbprint}.p12 - am I reading it wrong in this context?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Post a [mre] including a sample p12 file and debugging details(such as a stack trace). Also are you sure the process has a privilege to read the p12 file?